# Converting Binary(16) to int with same result in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I have Binary(16) column in table 'Chip' with value 0xE1FC2E6F8674B7B9045C1104F9124C48 and in another table i have column chip_i which is type of integer that has the same value (but in int) = -116241336.
Im using SQL Server 2012.

How can i convert 0xE1FC2E6F8674B7B9045C1104F9124C48 to -116241336 in C#?

I tried to convert it like this:

```
  string hexString = "0xE1FC2E6F8674B7B9045C1104F9124C48";
  byte[] hexByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexString);
  var chip_i = BitConverter.ToInt32(hexByte, 0);
```

but the result is 826636336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-116241336` is simply the last 4 bytes treated as a raw little-endian integer; `0xF9124C48`. So: just use the last 4 bytes *as is*. No need for ASCII:

```
int chip_i = Convert.ToInt32(hexString.Substring(hexString.Length - 8, 8), 16);
```